# query on suggester while build dictionary

Tags: solr

My suggester conf:

```
 <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">titleSuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="field">name</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_pt</str>
    <str name="payloadField">type</str> 
    <str name="weightField">weightField</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="indexPath">/home/dev/suggestions</str>
  </lst>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">titleSuggester</str> 
    <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str> 
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

It's work! But, i neeed build my dictionary every hour, and this build takes 2 minutes. 
Every hour i run:

```
localhost:8983/solr/AutoComplete/suggest?suggest.q=term&suggest.build=true
```

During this time i need get results, but when i run a query as:

```
localhost:8983/solr/AutoComplete/suggest?suggest.q=term
```

i get this return(because build is running):

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">500</int>
<int name="QTime">5</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
<str name="msg">suggester was not built</str>
```

**What can I do to get results while the build is running?**

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I have the same problem (my rebuild may run an hour) and I came to this solution:

Configure two components, e.g. suggest_A and suggest_B with different indexPath values.
Configure two request handlers, e.g. suggest and suggest_Rebuild.
Assign suggest_A to suggest and suggest_B to suggest_Rebuild.
Do the rebuild on the suggest_Rebuild handler. After the rebuild is finished, switch the component assignment of both components via the config API (update-requesthandler).

The drawback of this solution is that you need the double disk space.